# Chrome uses too much ram

Tags: google-chrome, memory

I've noticed chrome is using quite a bit of my RAM. I've got a total of 8GB and the total consumption of Chrome is around 500mb with just 4 tabs: this one, 2 google tabs and a facebook tab. I've also noticed(using the chrome process manager) that facebook normally uses 150+ mb and the gpu process just a bit more. I've only got 3 plugins running which use about 30mb each so they're not the problem. I realise this is not too much in general, but it is is for a web browser.
I don't know if it's related anyhow but I frequently experience slow downs when surfing, especially on websites like facebook and youtube.
Is this normal?

I'm using version 25.0.1323.1 dev-m and I'm on windows 7, 64bit.

Edit: From the comments I understand that it's not something to worry about. I'll close this question and post another regarding the slows because it's not related to this one. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: superuser tab 55MB             Yahoo mail window wit hold streamlined interface 60MB.  Modern browsers need loads of RAM. 2BG ram would hurt a bit.    500MB (0.5GB) is nothing when you have 8GB So one wonders what the cause of the slowdown is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My chrome is close to using 2GB with all of its processes together. (although i have 3 windows and a bunch of tabs each)

Its a pretty standard thing for chrome, and other browsers for that matter.